# Merge two list of dictionaries based on specific key

Tags: python, dictionary

Ok, so I have this code.

```
data1 = [
    {'Id': 1}, 
    {'Id': 2}
]
data2 = [
    {'Id': 1, 'score': 100, 'testdata': 333}, 
    {'Id': 2, 'score': 200, 'testdata': 555}, 
    {'Id': 3, 'score': 300, 'testdata': 444}
]

expectedData = [
        {'Id': 1, 'Score': 100}, 
        {'Id': 2, 'Score': 200}
    ]


def merge_lists(data1, data2, key):
    merged = {}
    for item in data1+data2:
        if item[key] in merged:
            merged[item[key]].update(item)
        else:
            merged[item[key]] = item
    return [val for (_, val) in merged.items()]

merged = merge_lists(data1, data2, 'Id')

print merged
```

The problem is that this will merge every value(that's not 'id') in data2 into data1. I only want it to merge the key 'score', but I'm really not sure how to specify that key only. I've tried multiple other conditional statements  in order to specify the 'score' key. But I can't seem to get anything working.

Thanks for any help

Comment: What do you expect as the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could factory function like this

```
data1 = [
    {'Id': 1},
    {'Id': 2}
]
data2 = [
    {'Id': 1, 'score': 100, 'testdata': 333},
    {'Id': 2, 'score': 200, 'testdata': 555},
    {'Id': 3, 'score': 300, 'testdata': 444}
]

def get_score(list_of_dict, id_value):

    for dict_ in list_of_dict:
        if dict_["Id"] == id_value:
            return {"score": dict_["score"]}

res = data1.copy()

for dict_ in res:
    dict_.update(get_score(data2, dict_["Id"]))

print(res)
# [{'score': 100, 'Id': 1}, {'score': 200, 'Id': 2}]
```

Comment: If you are using Python 2, the `data1.copy()` wont work. Instead of that, add `import copy` and change the copy line to `res = copy.copy(data1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's code that will merge the way you want. Note that if there are multiple lists in `data2` with the correct matching key only the first one will be found.

```
data1 = [
    {'Id': 1}, 
    {'Id': 2},
]

data2 = [
    {'Id': 1, 'score': 100, 'testdata': 333}, 
    {'Id': 2, 'score': 200, 'testdata': 555}, 
    {'Id': 3, 'score': 300, 'testdata': 444},
]

def merge_lists(data1, data2, key):
    result = []
    for d1 in data1:
        val = d1[key]
        dnew = {key: val}
        for d2 in data2:
            if d2[key] == val:
                dnew['score'] = d2['score']
                break
        else:
            raise KeyError('No match for %r: %s' % (key, val))
        result.append(dnew)
    return result

merged = merge_lists(data1, data2, 'Id')
print merged
```

**output**

```
[{'score': 100, 'Id': 1}, {'score': 200, 'Id': 2}]
```

If we change `data1` to

```
data1 = [
    {'Id': 1}, 
    {'Id': 5},
    {'Id': 2},
]
```

Then we get this output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./qtest.py", line 45, in <module>
    merged = merge_lists(data1, data2, 'Id')
  File "./qtest.py", line 41, in merge_lists
    raise KeyError('No match for %r: %s' % (key, val))
KeyError: "No match for 'Id': 5"
```